# program starting next line of code when gzip is still running

Tags: shell, gzip

In a shell script first I am generating a file, then zipping it using gzip and then transferring it using scp to remote machine. The issue here before the gzip completes successfully the pointer going to the next line of code and so because of this I am having partial transfer of gz file in the remote machine.

What I mean here is gzip command is starting the zip but before the zip get completed (as file size is big, so it should take some time to complete the zip process), the next line of code is getting executed; which is scp and so I am having partial file transfer in the remote machine.

My question is what is the option for gzip which I can specify and with that the pointer shouldn't move to the next line of code before zip process gets completed successfully.

GZIP is used like below in my code :

```
gzip -c <filename> > <zip_filename> 2>&1 | tee -a <log_filename>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if I do this

```
gzip -cr /home/username > homefolder.gz
```

the bash waits till end of the command, before executing the next (even if used in a script).

However, if I'm mistaken or your ran a command in the background, you can wait till gzip is finished, using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

gzip -cr "$1" > "$1.gz" &
while true; do
    if fuser -s "$1" "$1.gz"; then
        echo "gzip still compressing '$1'"
    else
        echo "gzip finished compressing '$1' (archive is '$1.gz')"
        break
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Or if you just want to wait and do nothing more, it's even simpler:

```
gzip -cr "$1" > "$1.gz"
while fuser -s "$1" "$1.gz"; do :; done
# copy your file wherever you want
```